# Android type face not working

Tags: android, typeface

I am trying to use the AndroidClock typeface on Android 2.2.2, well because it looks good, but when I go to use it only some of the text is set.

[image: AndroidClock.ttf]

Its extremely odd. Anyone have any idea?

I am using this to set the typeface

```
mCountdown.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AndroidClock.ttf"));
```

And this is what it looks like normally

[image: Countdown]

Heres the font in font viewer or what ever you want to call it

[image: Font]

Comment: If you're under Windows, load the font into the font viewer and see if the letters are indeed there and rendered properly?

Comment: Check now. Everything works for the second one but not the first one

Comment: Funny! What's the layout for that where you're outputting the text with the Roboto font? BTW is it me or the screenshot, uppercase letter 'A' looks funny to me...

Comment: The uppercase A in the second line is the only one that IS SET

Comment: Uhhh sorry, was referring to the font viewer...

Comment: Oh yeah it does. But when I use the same file on my 4.0.3 tablet it works perfect

Comment: Well, its not surprising it works fine on 4.0.3 tablet anyway as Roboto is there in place... have a look at this - https://github.com/phalt/TypeFaceUtility I recall seeing a source on github where you can set the typeface at design time... cannot remember where though!

Comment: Think it was this - not 100% sure if that's the one.. http://willowtreeapps.github.com/OAK/ <- TextViewWithFont

Comment: Hmmm, I have no idea what's happening D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason that it wasn't working... the typeface I was using only actually used the letters `A, P and M`, for `AM` and `PM`, numbers worked fine for obvious reasons.